# What's the differences between yum list updates and yum list obsoletes?

Tags: yum, software-updates

The document states:

> yum list obsoletes
>
> List the packages installed on the system that are obsoleted by packages in any yum repository listed in the config file.
>
> yum list updates
>
> List all packages with updates available in the yum repositories.

As I understand, if a package has update available, it is obsolete, right? So what's the differences between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't have all the packages from the repository on your local system but only a subset of them.

`yum list updates` lists all packages *in the repositories* that have updates. This is a superset of the packages on your system that have updates available.

The usual command for checking whether there are updates for the packages *on your system* is `yum check-update`, which has the following description in the man page (emphasis mine):

> Implemented so you could know if your machine had any updates
>   that needed to be applied without running it interactively.
>   Returns exit value of 100 if there are packages available for
>   an update. Also returns a **list of the packages to be updated**
>   in list format. Returns 0 if no packages are available for
>   update. Returns 1 if an error occurred.  Running **in verbose
>   mode also shows obsoletes**.

One interesting difference between `yum list obsoletes` and `yum check-update` is that the former command also accepts a glob expression to narrow down the list of packages that may be obsoleted by packages in the repositories. `yum check-update` does not accept such a glob expression.